# How do I pick 2 random items from a Python set?

Tags: python, random

I currently have a Python set of n size where n >= 0.  Is there a quick 1 or 2 lines Python solution to do it?  For example, the set will look like:

```
fruits = set(['apple', 'orange', 'watermelon', 'grape'])
```

The goal is to pick 2 random items from the above and it's possible that the above set can contain 0, 1 or more items.  The only way I can think of doing the above is to convert the set to a list(mutable) from where I can access 2 random unique index within the length of the set.

Comment: how are you going to pick to items from 0- or 1-item list?

Comment: The following should take care of that:
import random
vals = set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
random.sample(vals, min(len(vals),2))

Answer (score 342, accepted):

Use the `random` module: http://docs.python.org/library/random.html

```
import random
random.sample(set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]), 2)
```

This samples the two values *without* replacement (so the two values are different).

Comment: and can be used with `set` as well

Comment: Consider using a set in your example. The question explicitely asks for a set (which cannot be passed to `random.choice()` for example) so I'd say it'd improve the answer.

Comment: It's worth noting that internally, this turns the set into a list or tuple (depending on the sizes of the set and the sample) and then runs the sampling procedure. It won't, say, run [reservoir sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling) or some other algorithm that works on non-indexable collections.

Comment: Does the set() has any effect here? it should be exactly the same as doing:

random.sample([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 2)

Comment: from the docs: Return a k (2nd argument, k=2 above) length list of *unique* elements.

Comment: What if I wanna get the rest of items after the random choice?

Comment: You should mention if this is a random choice with or without replacement

Comment: will it work with set of strings?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica but on the wikipedia they are using indexes to acces an nth element from the sequence. Reservoir sampling thus needs indexable collection!

Comment: @AdamBajger: That's an artifact of the pseudocode notation used. Reservoir sampling does not need an indexable collection. [It's straightforward to implement with just an iterator.](https://ideone.com/FcybvK)

Comment: `X = {1,2,3,4}; random.sample(X, 1)` DeprecationWarning: Sampling from a set deprecated since Python 3.9 and will be removed in a subsequent version.