# Choose a non-repeating random element from a list using Python

Tags: python, list, random

I have this list:

```
pics = [i for i in glob.glob("*.jpg")]
choice = random.choice(pics)
```

and the code below the list was used to select a random image from a list. My problem is that it isn't unique and lots of pictures repeat.. Is there any way to overcome that?

Comment: Aside: `[i for i in glob.glob("*.jpg")]` is the same as `glob.glob("*.jpg")`.  Unless you're processing the filenames, there's no need for a listcomp here.

Comment: You may want to look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13628808/1066336).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pick N distinct items at random from sequence of unknown length, in only one iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690009/pick-n-distinct-items-at-random-from-sequence-of-unknown-length-in-only-one-ite)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) to choose random non-repeating elements:

```
>>> import random
>>> random.sample(glob.glob('*.jpg'), number_of_images_to_choose)
```

`random.sample` returns a `list` object.

*Side note:* there's no need in list comprehension, unless you're planning to filter the result of `glob.glob`.