# Python - getting 9 random words from an array

Tags: arrays

I have and array containing 10 words and i need to take out 9 words that are not the same; and put them into another array.
The array:
array = ["night", "smoke", "ghost", "tooth", "about", "camel", "brown", "funny", "chair", "price"]
8 bit swog swig

Comment: This question has been asked a hell lot of times. Nevertheless, I'll post my answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python choose a non-repeating random element from a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24087435/python-choose-a-non-repeating-random-element-from-a-list)

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

array = ["night", "smoke", "ghost", "tooth", "about", "camel", "brown", "funny", "chair", "price"]
new_array = random.sample(array, 9)
```

P.S.

Lists are not arrays. Python has built-in arrays, but they are rarely used.