# How to get a random value that cannot be equal to another value?

Tags: python

```
firstrandom = random.randint(1,2)
secondrandom = random.randint(1,2)
```

I just need the `secondrandom` variable to not equal the `firstrandom` variable, but I don't know how to.

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13628725/how-to-generate-random-numbers-that-are-different

Comment: In this case, it's easy. Whichever one `firstrandom` is, `secondrandom` is the *other* one. `secondrandom` isn't actually random; it's a function of the first value.

Comment: The second number isn't random if there's a limitation put on its value. A simple solution is, after getting the first number, loop until you get something that's not equal to it from `randint()`.

Comment: @martineau, simple, but less efficient than using `random.sample`.

Answer (score 2):

Some potential options:

1. In this case, since both variables can only either be `1` or `2`, just make `secondrandom = 1 + (firstrandom % 2)`.
2. Put the second `randint` in a loop and only exit the loop when the value is different from `firstrandom`.
3. Enumerate the valid values first, then pick a [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) of the allowed values.

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint

x = randint(0,4)
y = randint(0,4)
while x == y:
    y = randint(0,4)
```

While loop just repeats if x and y are equal. This works for whatever range you feed into randint.

Comment: Non-deterministic in runtime, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Any answer that involves looping to check if a value has already been picked is going to have non-deterministic runtime. It could run forever, or take two iterations.

Instead, use `random.sample` to ensure random picks from a range are unique.

```
>>> import random
>>> random.sample(range(1, 6), 2)
[2, 3]
>>> random.sample(range(1, 6), 2)
[1, 2]
>>> random.sample(range(1, 6), 2)
[1, 2]
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try this function, it returns a pair of two random integers that are not equal to each other:

```
import random
def randomPair(start, stop):
    n1 = random.randint(start, stop)
    n2 = random.randint(start, stop)
    if start!=stop:
        while n1 == n2: n2 = random.randint(start, stop) 
    return n1, n2
```

Comment: Avoid code only answer and provide an explanation.

Comment: @Itération122442 thank you i will try my best next time

Comment: I would edit this answer and add more detail or you risk it being deleted for insufficient explanation on how it helps answer the question.

Comment: This is pretty inefficient vs. the approach using `random.sample`.