# Python, Adding all lines with a certain string from a file to list then randomly choosing which string to print?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random
com=input("")
if com.startswith("/tip"):
    numlines=sum(1 for line in open("C:\\Users\\Jace\\Desktop\\Python Programs\\Quote\\tip.txt"))-1
    randomint=random.randint(0, numlines)
    with open("C:\\Users\\Jace\\Desktop\\Python Programs\\Quote\\tip.txt", "r") as f:
        i=1
        for line in f:
            if i==randomint:
                break
            i+=1
    print(line.strip("\n"))
```

This is the part of the code for my random tips from a file so far. I wish to add another part of code where it adds all strings with any occurrence of the input placed after "/tip ", for example, if I were to type "/tip Hello", it would compile all lines in the text file with "Hello" in the string and do a random.choice() from the list, printing the one chosen. I don't really know where to start with this, any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show tip.txt

Comment: In your example, ```line``` is a string - you could use [```in```](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations) to see if the tip is in the string.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to store all of the lines in a list. You can read the lines, selecting one at random and discarding the rest. This is called "resevoir sampling".

Your code might look like this:

```
import random

def random_line(iterator):
    result = None
    for n, item in enumerate(iterator):
        if random.randint(0,n) == 0:
            result = item
    return result

# A random line
with open('tip.txt') as f:
    print random_line(f) or "No tip for you!"

# A random line that has 'Hello'
with open('tip.txt') as f:
    print random_line(line for line in f if 'Hello' in line) or "nothin!"
```

As a more special case, this code randomly chooses a matching line from the tips file, but falls back to a random non-matching line if no match exists. It has the advantages of reading the input file exactly once, and not having to store the entire tips file in memory.

```
import random

def random_line_with_fallback(iterator, match = lambda x: True):
    result_match = None
    result_all = None
    n_match = n_all = 0
    for item in iterator:
        if match(item):
            if random.randint(0, n_match) == 0:
                result_match = item
            n_match += 1
        if random.randint(0, n_all) == 0:
            result_all = item
        n_all += 1
    return (result_match or result_all).strip()

# A random line
with open('tip.txt') as f:
    print random_line_with_fallback(f)

# Another way to do a random line. This depends upon
# the Python feature that  "'' in line" will always be True. 
com = ''
with open('tip.txt') as f:
    print random_line_with_fallback(f, lambda line: com in line)

# A random line that has 'Hello', if possible
com = 'Hello'
with open('tip.txt') as f:
    print random_line_with_fallback(f, lambda line: com in line)
```

References:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/23840292/8747
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling

Comment: How would I make it so that it would default to the 'random line' if the 'random line with hello' doesn't exist? I've been trying `if com in line:` etc, and trying to adapt your code, but it doesn't seem to want to work when I make additions, saying that **line** doesn't exist at that point

Comment: I would want to preserve the single-pass non-accumulating nature of the reservoir algorithm. I have included an example in my recent edit.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want, process each line of a text file, checking if the line has the word you're looking for.  If so, add it to a list, and the randomly select one "line" for all possible "lines".

```
lines = []
with open("tip.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if com in line:
            lines.append(line)
print(random.choice(lines))
```

Comment: `print(random.choice(lines))` is much cleaner than `print( lines[ random.randint(0, len(lines)-1) ] )`