# Can I set condition for the random.randint() function in python

Tags: python, list, random

```
WORDS=("lorem","ipsum","python")
words = random.choice(WORDS)
correct = words
length = 0
while length <len(words):
    i = random.randint(0,len(words))
    print(words[i],end=" ")
    length +=1
```

I am trying to make a word jumble game, where letters in a word are supposed to mash up. I wanted to ask if I can set a condition so that the `i`do not repeat the same value over and over again

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [shuffling-a-list-of-objects-in-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/976882/shuffling-a-list-of-objects-in-python) might help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-do-i-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list-using-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pick N items at random from sequence of unknown length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690009/pick-n-items-at-random-from-sequence-of-unknown-length)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle) which does *in-place* shuffling. For example:

```
>>> import random
>>> WORDS = ["lorem","ipsum","python"]  # But you need `list` not `tuple`; 
                                        # tuples are immutable
>>> random.shuffle(WORDS)
>>> WORDS  # List is shuffled
['ipsum', 'python', 'lorem']
```

For shuffling each word within the tuple you have, you need to do:

```
shuffled_words= []

for word in WORDS:
    word_list = list(word)  # Typecast `str` to `list`
    random.shuffle(word_list)  # shuffle the list
    shuffled_words.append(''.join(word_list)) # join the list to make `str`
```

Value hold by `shuffled_words` list will be:

```
>>> shuffled_words
['omelr', 'spmiu', 'pynhot']
```

Comment: But I want to jumble the letters in a word, not the items in the list/tuple

Answer (score 1):

use `random.sample` (using `random.shuffle` needs to create a list since it works in-place):

```
shuffled = "".join(random.sample(words,len(words)))
```

BTW: Your code is bound to crash because it's using `random.randint` which may pick `len(words)` which is out of range.
You should have chosen `random.randrange`

Comment: I think, creating a copy of list and do shuffle on it is better than doing `join` and calculating `len(words)` on list returned by `random.sample`. May be it is opinion based

Comment: More to the point, the use case for `sample` is when you need *fewer* items than there are in the population you're taking a sample from. `sample` is slower than `shuffle` because it does more, e.g. it allocates a separate set to keep track of the items it's already seen. As a result, `y = random.sample(x, len(x))` is an inefficient way to express `y = x[:]; random.shuffle(y)`.

Answer (score 0):

I've written up a fairly simple class for you and will detail the usage afterwards

```
from random import random
from math import floor

class FairDice():
    def __init__(self, sides = 6):
        self.sides = sides
        self.history = []
        self.last = None
    def roll(self):
        number = random()
        roll = int(floor(number * self.sides)) + 1
        return roll

    def statefull_roll(self, remember = None):
        while True:
            roll = self.roll()
            remember = self.sides if remember is None else remember
            if len(self.history) >= remember:
                return None

            if roll not in self.history:
                self.history.append(roll)
                return roll

    def forget_history(self):
        self.history = []  

    def forget_one(self):
        self.history = self.history[1:]
```

I've created this `FairDice` class. You can do regular rolls by calling `.roll()` function. Or you can do rolls that remember what has been rolled by calling the `statefull_roll()` method. If there are no numbers left then None is returned. You can also call the `forget_history()` function to forget history.

Here is an example of usage:

```
dice = FiarDice(25) #creates a 25 sided dice  

for x in range(10):
    print("Regular Roll gives you: ", dice.roll())  

for x in range(25):
    print("Your sort of Roll gives you: ", dice.statefull_roll()) 

print ( dice.statefull_roll()) # Should return none after exhausting all possible characters. 

dice.forget_history() # forgets that any value have been recorded at all
```

Lets say that it's ok to repeat letters after 5 rolls. I've added the `none`.

```
roll = dice.statefull_roll(remember = 5)
```

This will return None after 5 rolls after which all you have to do is...

```
if roll is None:
    dice.forget_one()  
    roll = dice.statefull_roll(remember = 5)
```

`forget_one` forgets your oldest roll.

What I've written is not much, but works and is flexible enough for usage in your game.

Answer (score -1):

No, but you can loop until you get a number you haven't seen yet:

```
import random

WORDS = ("lorem", "ipsum", "python")
words = random.choice(WORDS)
correct = words
length = 0
seen = set()
i = 0
while length < len(words):
    while i in seen:
        i = random.randint(0, len(words)-1)
    seen.add(i)

    print(words[i], end=" ")
    length += 1
```

But (as the commenters have pointed out) there's a much more efficient way to shuffle the characters of a word:

```
import random

WORDS = ("lorem", "ipsum", "python")
word = random.choice(WORDS)

charlist = list(word)
random.shuffle(charlist)
print(" ".join(charlist), end=" ")
```

Comment: Sorry but I am just a beginner. Can u explain to me how does set() works?

Comment: that's not very efficient: in the end, you'll cast a lot of random numbers to avoid the ones already seen.

Comment: can u guide me why is "i in seen" true for the while loop to loop

Comment: @EricWatson if `i` is a member of the set `seen`, the expression `i in seen` is true.

Comment: but how is i a member of the set send?

Comment: @EricWatson We add it to `seen` on the next line: `seen.add(i)`