# Can I speedup an iterable class when I know it's length in advance?

Tags: python, performance, python-internals

[PEP 424](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0424/) mentions in the "Rationale" that:

> Being able to pre-allocate lists based on the expected size, as estimated by `__length_hint__` , can be a significant optimization. CPython has been observed to run some code faster than PyPy, purely because of this optimization being present.

So I asked myself the question that I'm now asking here: Is it possible to speed up some **iterable class processing an iterator** (when it's possible to correctly predict it's "length") based on this knowledge?

Comment: Generator functions have no control over the generator object produced when they are called other than the fact that their code object becomes the generator's .gi_code attribute.  In particular, they cannot cause a .__length_hint__ attribute.

Comment: Generators don't have anything they could use that length info for. They don't have a list object to preallocate.

Comment: "iterators that can predict the length of the resulting iterator"? You should edit your post once again :) +1 for the intention, though

Comment: @Rightleg Yeah, at some point my vocabulary just gave up. Sorry for the confusion. I hope I've clarified the intention now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting aside the generator/iterator terminology confusion, the `__length_hint__` method is a really minor optimization I would only use in special circumstances.  I wrote my own simple little test:

```
class Range:

    def __init__(self, n):
        self._n = n
        self._i = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        i = self._i
        if i >= self._n:
            raise StopIteration
        self._i += 1
        return i

class RangeWithHint(Range):

    def __length_hint__(self):
        return self._n
```

If this is used to generate a list of values, the advantage of preallocating the list only becomes measurable with really large lists of about a million elements, and even then is very small:

```
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> timeit("xs = list(Range(1000000))", "from __main__ import Range", number=10)
5.068971888250076
>>> timeit("xs = list(RangeWithHint(1000000))", "from __main__ import RangeWithHint", number=10)
4.7962311912107225
```

Takeaway: Python is already really, really fast at reallocating lists as they grow.  Don't assume that `__length_hint__` is going to vastly improve that speed.

Answer (score 1):

My conclusions about doing two experiments (one after receiving feedback of @TerryJanReedy):

There can be a *significant* (up to 50%) optimization in simple cases with long iterables but in absolute performance it's negligable as soon as some more complicated operations are performed with or on the item or the iterable is very short.

## Setup

I implemented one class that just iterates over some iterator and one more `map`-like that applies a function to each item. Both classes come in two variants, one without implementing a `__length_hint__` and one with it.

I choose `Cython` to remove as much Python overhead as possible:

```
from operator import length_hint

cdef class MyIter(object):
    cdef object it

    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.it = iter(iterable)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        return next(self.it)

cdef class MyIter2(object):
    cdef object it

    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.it = iter(iterable)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        return next(self.it)

    # --- This method is new ---
    def __length_hint__(self):
        return length_hint(self.it)

# Map-like classes

cdef class MyMap(object):
    cdef object func
    cdef object it

    def __init__(self, func, iterable):
        self.it = iter(iterable)
        self.func = func

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        return self.func(next(self.it))

cdef class MyMap2(object):
    cdef object func
    cdef object it

    def __init__(self, func, iterable):
        self.it = iter(iterable)
        self.func = func

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        return self.func(next(self.it))

    # --- This method is new ---
    def __length_hint__(self):
        return length_hint(self.it)
```

## Timings

I did the timing using Python 3.5 with Ipythons `%timeit` command:

```
import random

lengths1 = []
timing1 = []
timing2 = []

lengths2 = []
timing3 = []
timing4 = []

for _ in range(30):
    i = random.randint(1, 1000000)
    lengths1.append(i)
    lst = list(range(i))

    res1 = %timeit -o list(MyIter(lst))
    timing1.append(res1)
    res2 = %timeit -o list(MyIter2(lst))
    timing2.append(res2)

    i = random.randint(1, 100000)  # factor 10 less items
    lengths2.append(i)
    lst = list(range(i))

    res3 = %timeit -o list(MyMap(float, lst))
    timing3.append(res3)
    res4 = %timeit -o list(MyMap2(float, lst))
    timing4.append(res4)
```

The results of the time difference (`timing1 - timing2`) and relative time difference (`100 * (timing1 - timing2) / timing1`):

### MyIter

[image]

This shows a **significant optimization** (up to 50%) for long iterables.

### MyMap

[image]

So the one with the `__length_hint__` is sometimes faster but not what I would call *significant*.

Comment: Your classes are iterator classes, not generator functions, which is why you *could* add a __length_hint__ methods.  I confirmed that length_hint(iter(somelist)) works as expected, returning len(somelist).  But how did you run your code?  `%timeit -o list(MyMap(float, lst))` is not legal Python.  And with what underlying Python?  I cannot help but wonder if there is some random overhead noise confusing the result.  Also, I would remove the mapping operation to see just the effect of having a length hint.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy That's IPython (https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit), what do you mean with the underlying python? I'll update the answer without a mapping operation later.

Comment: AFAIK, IPython, like IDLE, is written in Python and at any time is running on some particular version of Python.  I was asking about the version, which you since said is 3.5.  Sorry about not being clear.