# Using python, how do you select a random row of a csv file?

Tags: python, csv, random, row

I need to select a random word from a csv file and I just don't know how to start it off. All the words are in one column, but I want to get a random row so as I can output a random word. Any thoughts?

Comment: Use the [**`random`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) and [**`csv`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) modules.

Comment: I would count the number of rows. From this a random integer could be generated in the range of 1 to number of rows.
After you have done this simply read the word off at that row?

Comment: If the file is too large to read into memory all at once, you could use [resevoir sampling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690009/pick-n-items-at-random-from-sequence-of-unknown-length).

Answer (score 12):

Use the [**`random`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) and [**`csv`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) modules.

If your `csv` file is small enough to fit into memory, you could read the whole thing then select a line:

```
import csv
import random

with open(filename) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    chosen_row = random.choice(list(reader))
```

You have to read in the whole file at once because `choice` needs to know how many rows there are.

If you're happy making more than one pass over the data you could count the rows and then choose a random row and read in the file again up to that row:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    lines = sum(1 for line in f)
    line_number = random.randrange(lines)

with open(filename) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    chosen_row = next(row for row_number, row in enumerate(reader)
                      if row_number == line_number)
```

If you want to incrementally, and randomly, choose a row, without knowing how many rows there will be, you can use [reservoir sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling#Example_implementation). This may be slower, as it will make multiple random choices until it runs out of rows, but it will only need one row in memory at a time:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for index, row in enumerate(reader):
        if index == 0:
            chosen_row = row
        else:
            r = random.randint(0, index)
            if r == 0:
                chosen_row = row
```

Comment: Excellent way to count lines in a file.

Answer (score 8):

You could use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
csvfile = pd.read_csv('/your/file/path/here')
print csvfile.sample()
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you stated that all words are in one column, that makes it easier to parse the file. Here is my solution:

```
import random

with open('random_word_from_file.txt') as f:
    words = f.read().split()
    my_pick = random.choice(words)
    print my_pick
```

## Notes

- In this solution, I assume the size of the file reasonably fits in memory
- I used `f.read().split()` instead of `f.readlines()` because the later does not strip new line characters off the words
- Once having a list of words, it is a matter of calling `random.choice()` to pick one randomly