# Adding (non-repeating) Random Numbers to Each Line of .txt File

Tags: python, random, text, python-itertools, edge-list

I'm creating a .txt file that has four soldiers on a team ranking each other in order of merit. Soldiers do not rank themselves.

I have the following code:

```
import itertools

# create a list of 4 soldiers
numSoldiers=4
soldiers = []
for i in range(1,numSoldiers+1):
    soldiers.append('soldier'+str(i))

# create list of all permutations of 2 soldiers
perms = list(itertools.permutations(soldiers, 2))

# list of possible rankings (soldier does not rank himself/herself)
possRanks = list(range(1,len(soldiers)))

# create the edgelist .txt file with randomized rankings
open('peerRankingsEdgelist.txt', 'w').close() #delete contents of .txt file at the start

file = open('peerRankingsEdgelist.txt', 'w')

for i in perms:
    file.write(i[0] + ', ' + i[1] + '\n')

file.close() #close file
```

which produces the following output in a .txt file:

```
soldier1, soldier2
soldier1, soldier3
soldier1, soldier4
soldier2, soldier1
soldier2, soldier3
soldier2, soldier4
soldier3, soldier1
soldier3, soldier2
soldier3, soldier4
soldier4, soldier1
soldier4, soldier2
soldier4, soldier3
```

For each set of three lines (the sets of lines that start with the same `soldier`), I want to add a randomized ranking that comes from `possRanks`, where `possRanks = [1, 2, 3]`. The problem is that I can't completely randomize it because then the rankings might repeat. For example, `soldier1` might rank both `soldier2` and `soldier3` with a ranking of `1`, which I cannot have.

A correct example output would be the following:

```
soldier1, soldier2, 3
soldier1, soldier3, 1
soldier1, soldier4, 2
soldier2, soldier1, 1
soldier2, soldier3, 2
soldier2, soldier4, 3
soldier3, soldier1, 2
soldier3, soldier2, 1
soldier3, soldier4, 3
soldier4, soldier1, 1
soldier4, soldier2, 2
soldier4, soldier3, 3
```

Here, `soldier1` ranks `soldier2` with a value of `3`, `soldier3` with a value of `1`, and `soldier4` with a value of `2`.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How do I append a randomized, non-repeating ranking from `possRanks` to each set of three lines in the .txt file?

Comment: `random.shuffle` can be useful here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pick N distinct items at random from sequence of unknown length, in only one iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690009/pick-n-distinct-items-at-random-from-sequence-of-unknown-length-in-only-one-ite) ... there are other possible answers searching with variations of `python choose random items from a list without repeating site:stackoverflow.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your file as an example `data.txt`:

```
soldier1, soldier2
soldier1, soldier3
soldier1, soldier4
soldier2, soldier1
soldier2, soldier3
soldier2, soldier4
soldier3, soldier1
soldier3, soldier2
soldier3, soldier4
soldier4, soldier1
soldier4, soldier2
soldier4, soldier3
```

We could read the file in N sized chunks using the [itertools grouper recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes), shuffle `possRanks` with [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle), then [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) each group with each shuffled rank. We can then open a new file to write to, such as `output.txt`.

```
from random import shuffle
from itertools import zip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

possRanks = [1, 2, 3]

with open("data.txt") as f, open("output.txt", mode="w") as o:
    for line in grouper(map(str.strip, f), len(possRanks), ''):
        shuffle(possRanks)
        for group, rank in zip(line, possRanks):
            o.write(f"{group}, {rank}\n")
```

Which will write a random shuffling of ranks to `output.txt` every time you run the above:

```
soldier1, soldier2, 2
soldier1, soldier3, 1
soldier1, soldier4, 3
soldier2, soldier1, 1
soldier2, soldier3, 3
soldier2, soldier4, 2
soldier3, soldier1, 2
soldier3, soldier2, 3
soldier3, soldier4, 1
soldier4, soldier1, 3
soldier4, soldier2, 1
soldier4, soldier3, 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way just using `enum` which might be easier to parse;

```
import itertools
import random

# create a list of 4 soldiers
numSoldiers=4
soldiers = []
for i in range(1,numSoldiers+1):
    soldiers.append('soldier'+str(i))

# create list of all permutations of 2 soldiers
perms = list(itertools.permutations(soldiers, 2))

# list of possible rankings (soldier does not rank himself/herself)
possRanks = list(range(1,len(soldiers)))

# create the edgelist .txt file with randomized rankings
open('peerRankingsEdgelist.txt', 'w').close() #delete contents of .txt file at the start

file = open('peerRankingsEdgelist.txt', 'w')

for num, i in enumerate(perms):
    if num % len(possRanks) == 0:
        shuffled_ranks = possRanks.copy()
        random.shuffle(shuffled_ranks)

    random_rank = str(shuffled_ranks.pop())

    line = (i[0]) + ', ' + i[1] + ',' + random_rank + '\n'


    file.write(line)

file.close() #close file
```

So the only part I have changed is here:

```
for num, i in enumerate(perms):
        if num % len(possRanks) == 0:
            shuffled_ranks = possRanks.copy()
            random.shuffle(shuffled_ranks)

        random_rank = str(shuffled_ranks.pop())

        line = (i[0]) + ', ' + i[1] + ',' + random_rank + '\n'
```

Basically I am using `enumerate` to count each iteration, and am only creating 
new random list of `possRanks` every `x` amount of iterations, where `x` is equal to the `len of possRanks`.
We then just pop each item from the list, basically exhausting the list every `x` iteration, and create a new list after exhaustion.