# Python Get Random Sample of List of Tuples

Tags: python, list, random

I have a list of over million tuples and want a list of 100,000 tuples randomly sampled from that original list without replacement.  I have read:

[How do I pick 2 random items from a Python set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262955/how-do-i-pick-2-random-items-from-a-python-set)

but the solution provided (using random.sample while casting list to a set) does not work for tuples.

I am using Python 2.7

Comment: Can you explain how your data is stored in more detail? The example given works fine for me for lists, tuples, and lists of tuples.

Comment: The problem comes from casting to a set, as tuples cannot be hashed.  The data I am trying to sample without replacement is a list of tuples.

Comment: Don't cast it to a set then. `random.sample([(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(1,41)],2)` should work fine.

Comment: Don't call `set` on it.

Comment: Tuples **can** be hashed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sample your list regardless of if the elements are hashable or not:

```python
data = create_dataset() # List of data to be sampled

n_samples = 100000
samples = random.sample(data,n_samples)
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if I fully understand your question, but `random.sample` can accept both lists and tuples:

```
random.sample([1,2,3,4,5],2)
Out[620]: [2, 5]

random.sample((1,2,3,4,5),2)
Out[621]: [4, 1]
```

Comment: I though random.sample sampled with replacement and that is why, in the link I provided in the question, they cast the list to a set

Comment: No it's sampling without replacement.

Comment: @Marjoram: No, they call `set` because the question is specifically about sampling from sets, and before the introduction of set literals, `set([a, b, c])` was the way to create a set of `a`, `b`, and `c`.